# How to convert a curve-based animation into an exportable keyframe amination for a video game?

Tags: animation, modifiers, export

I have a conveyor belt animation obtained by moving on an axis a plane to which is applied a list of modifiers.
The rolling animation is due to the "Curve" modifier, the first one in the list :

[image: modifiers list]
[image]

As it is, it is impossible to export the object and its animation for real time use.

I have already looked at other posts on stackexchange with a similar question, but the answers don't seem relevant in my case.The treadmill is one single object.

Any idea how to export the object and its animation so that it can be used in real time?
Keyframes or ShapeKeys?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you animating this?

Comment: Hi,
Simply by animating (2 keyframe) the Y-coordinate of the base object to which the Curve modifier is applied.